# How many passes does a c compiler do?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int res;
    funcAdd(10,20);
}

int funcAdd(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

In the above program, main does not recognize funcAdd() since it is defined after main and there is no declaration in the beginning.  If C compiler did 2 passes of a program then this must not be an issue since it will know the function funcAdd() is be defined in the second pass. Does this mean C is one pass compiler? Kindly clarify my doubt.

Comment: it have nothing do to with validity of the program

Comment: Fallacy of affirmation of the consequent. That a one-pass compiler can't recognize funcAdd at the point of call does not imply that a compiler that doesn't recognize funcAdd at the point of call is one-pass.

Answer (score 11):

The C language doesn't specify how many passes a compiler must take.  However, it /does/ specify that functions must be declared before they are used.  Hence, your code is invalid, regardless of how many passes the compiler makes.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is invalid. A C compiler can make as many passes as it wants, but it still must return an error in this case because the standard says so.